# Start ViewPagerController with second UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

i have a viewpagercontroller and have it running correctly with 3 pre set UIViewControllers, however when i load the app it first displays the first UIViewController, i would instead, like to display the second UIViewController first, however i am having trouble achieving this.

Here is my ViewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is my orderedViewControllers

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newProfileViewController(vc: "UserContentViewController"),
            self.newProfileViewController(vc: "ProfileViewController"),
            self.newProfileViewController(vc: "NotificationViewController")]
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can this function with your desired index,

```
func scrollToViewController(index newIndex: Int) {
    if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let currentIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) {
            let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = newIndex >= currentIndex ? .Forward : .Reverse
            let nextViewController = orderedViewControllers[newIndex]
            scrollToViewController(nextViewController, direction: direction)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think they want it to scroll like this, this will visibly animate to the second vc. I think they want it to just load up on the second view controller.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the first bit of code that sets the viewcontrollers:

So change this:

```
if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
    setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                       direction: .forward,
                       animated: true,
                       completion: nil)
}
```

To this:

```
if orderedViewControllers.count > 0 {
    let secondViewController = orderedViewControllers[1]
        setViewControllers([secondViewController],
                       direction: .forward,
                       animated: false,
                       completion: nil)
}
```

This will set the page view controller to the second view controller straight away and then your delegate methods on the page view controller should handle the swiping before and after to load the correct view controller.